# How can I change the height of a TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-textinputfield

I want to change the height of a `TextField` in Flutter but I don't know which one is the best way.

1. Wrap the `TextField` in a `SizedBox`
2. Use content `padding` property

If you have some experience, please share it.
I just want to know the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1
`const SizedBox(width: 100.0,child: TextField())`

Solution 2

`const TextField( decoration: InputDecoration( contentPadding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:40.0) ,) ,)`

You can also edit the `maxLines:` property to make the box bigger

Answer (score 1):

Both methods achieve the goal of changing the height of the `TextField`.I mostly used wrap with sizedbox.Height and width used mediaquery for responsive Ui.